# how can I simply store level data as an array and load it again?

Tags: swift, storage, nsarray, file-manager

I admit I am a newbee, although I have been writing this for 1.5 years now, I still feel as a beginner sometimes.

I am trying to write an action game with a spaceship flying through different levels.
For a while, it was sufficient to store the level data in UserDefaults, but now I would like to edit several levels and thus need a broader approach.

So I am basically using the same way of storing the data as I did before, which seems to work fine - it is saved, I can see it and read it.
For the storage, the data (Int64 values) is written to a long array, called LevelSave, then written to 'savestring' and finally saved as 'Level1'

```
        var savestring : [AnyObject?]
        savestring = LevelSave as [AnyObject?]
        let objCArray = NSMutableArray()
        objCArray.add(savestring)
        objCArray.write(toFile: getFilePath(fileName: "Level1"), atomically: true)
```

However, when I can't seem to get beyond the point where I load the data:

```
        if let _ = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: getFilePath(fileName: "Level1")) {
                    let arrayb = NSArray(contentsOfFile: getFilePath(fileName: "Level1"))}
```

It is somehow stored in the NSArray, which I can't properly access. I mean, I can print out the array as a whole, but cannot access the individual elements, not even the number of elements required to set the dimensions for the required array to work with.
I have searched for this question a lot, but it seems there is no-one fighting with a similar issue.
I don't want to get into too much detail with NSArray, I hope this is the only time I need it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Well since you are using Swift you should stop using any NS classes and replace them with native types and why an array of AnyObject, you know the content of the array (Int64) don't you? Also why Int64 instead of Int?

Comment: so can you tell me (show me) how to do it without NS? 
'any object' because that's what I found in a book. I am open for any suggestion.
Int64 is of course used because the numbers are huge.

Comment: To comment your advice to stop using NS classes, I found that these are required to write to files.

Comment: You can write to files using native swift classes of course.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it. A workaround though.
I converted the array to a text-string, to which I could add all elements. And saved that string.
After loading the file, I convert the string to separate string components, and then convert those string numbers into the good old integers, one by one in a for-in-loop.
It works.
Anyway, the documentation (particularly that from Apple) for these very complex matters is often so poor, that it drives me mad and from time to time I am thinking about quitting.
Stackoverflow.com is a great institution, thank you for that. Keeps me going!

Comment: Please post only an answer to the question and leave out any personal ramblings and opinions,.